# Getting error when deploying Serverless project

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm getting the following error when deploying my Serverless app:

```
  Range Error --------------------------------------------

    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:193:23)
  at ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:195:28)
  at ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:195:28)
  at ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:195:28)
  at ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:195:28)
  ...
 at new ReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:195:28)
      at Object.createReadStream (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:237:12)
      at copyFile (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/ncp.js:98:25)
      at /Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/ncp.js:82:9
      at /Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/ncp.js:208:43
      at callback (/Users/ist1/Dev/homestop/api/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:289:20)
      at callback (/Users/ist1/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:295:20)
      at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
```

Has anyone experienced this? It was working previously. What's going wrong?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with after upgrading serverless to version `1.52.0`.
Workaround by downgrading to previous version by running `npm i -g serverless@1.51.0`

Comment: See here https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6667

Comment: Thanks, I also ended up downgrading it to `1.51.0`.